# Mocking a call to an object with a property of type List

Tags: c#, .net, properties, mocking, moq

I am learning Moq, and I would like to mock an interface ISecureAsset that has a property Contexts which returns a list of SecurityContexts. I am testing a method on another class that accesses the Contexts property for authorization.

```
public interface ISecureAsset {

   List<SecurityContext> Contexts { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this with Moq? I want to be able to set the values in the Contexts list as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set up the property to return a fake list of SecurityContexts.

```
var mockAsset = new Mock<ISecureAsset>();

var listOfContexts = new List<SecurityContext>();
//add any fake contexts here

mockAsset.Setup(x => x.Contexts).Returns(listOfContexts);
```

The [Moq quickstart guide](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) may be of some assistance to you.

Comment: Accepted in under a minute... is that some kind of record?

Answer (score 3):

```
var mockSecureAsset = new Mock<ISecureAsset>();
mockSecureAsset.SetupGet(sa => sa.Contexts).Return(new List<SecurityContext>());
```

or

```
mockSecureAsset.SetupProperty(sa => sa.Contexts);
mockSecureAsset.Object.Contexts = new List<SecurityContext>();
```